# Какой лучше выбрать цикл, как реализовать подстановку переменных?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, циклы, переменные

Функция удаления сообщения в Телеграм боте на aiogram.
Есть файл .txt в котором имеются числа записанные построчно(id пользователя и id сообщения)
Их много. У каждого id пользователя свой id сообщения. Файл с данными можно поменять как угодно для удобства использования.
Необходимо организовать подстановку всех данных поочерёдно в "bot.delete_message()" и зациклить этот процесс, чтобы процедура была выполнена для всех значений в файле с данными.

#Удаление сообщений

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals=["delmess"]))
async def delete_links(message: types.Message):
    if int(message.chat.id) == config.owner:
        await bot.delete_message(281521204, 1735)
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `sqlite` если, как вы говорите "там их много". С помощью БД такие выборки делаются гораздо быстрее и проще. (буквально в 2-3 строки кода)

Comment: @namerek я же написал что БД можно поменять для удобства. Вопрос как лучше выгрузить переменные так чтобы цикле прокрутил все варианты и выполнил функцию для всех имеющихся переменных.